# c# Error With code Generator For 'MVC Controller with Views' using 'Add New Scaffolded Item'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I get a Error Message when I generate a 'new Scaffolded Item' from the Controller folder for a MVC View Pages.

Images [

[Controller Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grfiD.png)

[Add new Scaffolded Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6SBs.png)

[Add MVC Controller with views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETabq.png)

[Error Code "Microsoft Visual Studio"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwLlg.png)

]

This is the model that I used.

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name.")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public int ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product price.")]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8, 2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

   
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product Description.")]
    public int Description { get; set; }

    public byte [] Picture { get; set; }

    public int StockID { get; set; }
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product Category.")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string IdentityID { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser Identity { get; set; }
}
```

Application.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>
 
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" 
   Version="3.1.12" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" 
   Version="3.1.12" />
  <PackageReference 
   Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" 
    Version="3.1.12" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" 
    Version="3.1.12" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" 
    Version="3.1.12" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" 
    Version="3.1.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; 
       buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" 
      Version="3.1.12" />
   <PackageReference 
    Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" 
     Version="3.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A good place to start is [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search) the site to see if there's any answers here already. When you post a question, make sure to [follow the suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best possible answers. Make sure your question has [enough explanation and code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the folks who are trying to help you can see what you've tried, understand it, and reproduce your error.

Comment: Hi @AzRaeL,can you share your project file :`Application.csproj`.

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu, I added the Application.csproj Code to the question.

Comment: Hi @AzRaeL,does this solution works?

Comment: yes @Yinqiu, it works thanks

Comment: If it works, please feel free to [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) useful answers, which will help others facing same issue to find solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to the version mismatch between them, you can modify your `Application.csproj` as follows：

```
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" Version="3.1.12" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="3.1.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.13" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.13">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```